# How to make Spring with AspectJ weaver custom annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj

In our project we're trying to move from Spring standard AOP to AspectJ as explained in many places like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615728/the-old-transactional-from-within-the-same-class-situation) (we need to make transactional some private and protected methods).

We had been able to make this work fine with standard Spring annotations like `@Transactional`. But we face the problem that in our project there are some custom Annotations (not custom aspects) that are not recognized by AspectJ. For example, we have this annotation that 'extends' `@Transactional` (only modifies `rollbackFor` property):

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public @interface TransactionalWithCheckedException {

}
```

Any idea on how to tell AspectJ to weaver also this custom annotations? Is it possible? If not, should i build custom Aspects extending Spring ones (i.e.: for `@Transactional`).

For more information this is the aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <!-- Aparently no need to explicit declare aspects like the ones used by Spring @Transactional or @Async, they work fine. -->
  </aspects>
<weaver options="-XnoInline -Xreweavable -showWeaveInfo">
  <include within="com.mycompany.myproject..*" />
</weaver>
```

And part of Spring's context config file:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />
 <context:load-time-weaver />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, the Spring `@Transactional` annotation is not a meta-annotation, so it cannot be used on annotation types. Additionally, nothing in the spring transaction code would support this kind of usage. In order to support this kind of usage, you'll have to create a specialized aspect with the proper pointcuts to identify the join points at transaction boundaries, probably supporting both the original Spring `@Transactional` annotation and your custom annotation as well. You'll also need to provide the aspect with an implementation of `TransactionAttributeSource` to support you own source of metadata, in your case an implementation of that interface handling  `@TransactionalWithCheckedException` annotation (your point of interest will be the `TransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(Throwable ex)` method). You can then use `CompositeTransactionAttributeSource` as the implementation of the `TransactionAttributeSource` so you can combine the metadata sources supporting Spring's `@Transactional` annotation and your annotation as well.

To sum it up, you'll need these two things to handle special transaction attributes:

- a concrete Aspect supporting both your and Spring's annotations (probably a subclass of `AbstractTransactionAspect`, see `AnnotationTransactionAspect` for implementation ideas`
- a `TransactionAttributeSource` implementation handling your transaction annotation. Use `CompositeTransactionAttributeSource` to combine support for your metadata with spring's metadata (`AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource`).

Comment: I suposed that this was the right way to prceed in this case, but i hoped it should be another easier way. Thanks for your explanation.